# How to switch two ImageViews using an animation in JavaFX

Tags: java, fxml

I am coding a simple card game in Java using JavaFXML for the UI. I am using a GridPane to organize the card positions, some cells contain ImageViews ( max 1 per cell ) which contain playing cards images. I am facing an issue when I try to switch two cards on the screen using animations.

I started coding animations to make cards move but I realized a problem : I have for example an ImageView with the ID "wastePile" which contains the last card discarded and an ImageView with the ID "handCard" that contains the current card in the hand of the player. If I create a parallel transition that make the two ImageViews move and switch their positions, a the end of it the "wastePile" imageView will not be in its correct position on the screen anymore, so I created a function that, at the end of the animation, instantly switches the two ImageViews to their initial positions and then their content so that the user doesn't notice the switch. The mechanism I created only works for the first switch, after that cards start moving out of the screen as if coordinates were wrong, can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
public void cardsSwitchAnimation (ImageView image,Integer imageViewPosition) {

    ImageView destinationImage = imageViews.get(imageViewPosition);
    
    
    TranslateTransition translateFirstImage = getTranslateAnimation(image, destinationImage);
    TranslateTransition translateSecondImage = getTranslateAnimation(destinationImage, image);
    ParallelTransition pt = new ParallelTransition();
    pt.setDelay(Duration.millis(1000));
    pt.getChildren().add(translateFirstImage);
    pt.getChildren().add(translateSecondImage);
    pt.setOnFinished(e -> {
        ImageView destImage = imageViews.get(imageViewPosition);
        switchImages(image, destImage);
    });
    pt.play();
    return;
}

public TranslateTransition getTranslateAnimation(ImageView movingImage, ImageView destinationImage) {
    double startX = destinationImage.getBoundsInParent().getCenterX();
    double startY = destinationImage.getBoundsInParent().getCenterY();
    double destinationX = movingImage.getBoundsInParent().getCenterX();
    double destinationY = movingImage.getBoundsInParent().getCenterY();
    TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(1000), movingImage);
    translate.setByX( startX - destinationX );
    translate.setByY( startY - destinationY );
    return translate;
}

private void switchImages(ImageView image, ImageView destinationImage) {
    Image temporary = image.getImage();
    Double firstImageRotate = image.getRotate();
    Double firstImageX = image.getLayoutX();
    Double firstImageY = image.getLayoutY();
    Double secondImageX = destinationImage.getLayoutX();
    Double secondImageY = destinationImage.getLayoutY();
    
    
    image.setLayoutX(secondImageX - image.getLayoutX());
    image.setLayoutY(secondImageY - image.getLayoutY());
    image.setRotate(destinationImage.getRotate());
    image.setImage(destinationImage.getImage());
    
    destinationImage.setLayoutX(firstImageX - destinationImage.getLayoutX());
    destinationImage.setLayoutY(firstImageY - destinationImage.getLayoutY());
    destinationImage.setRotate(firstImageRotate);
    destinationImage.setImage(temporary);
}
```

Comment: can you please share the fxml and full code ? it will help to reproduce the situation in my local.